# URL Redirect, HTML, PHP

Tags: php, html, redirect

I want to link links on my website via `go.php?urlhere`, I have been told and I have tried using `go.php?url=urlhere` however the URL's to which I redirect, redirect to another URL with-in it for example `go.php?http://.com/click?p=0&a=0&url=http://.com`, many of the redirect I have tried to use simply copy the URL in the `go.php` file and use a meta refresh or a `window.location` reload; however they redirect to the second URL and not the first one. Sometimes when I do actually get it to redirect the first part of the redirected URL gets all the dots changed to "_" which stops it redirecting.

I want to have something like this website using on its "Buy It Now" buttons

http://www.searchchief.co.uk/Search/Sony-PSP-Go

Answer (score 1):

So I think this is what you are asking: **How do I redirect to a page using a url as a query string parameter?**

eg.

```
http://www.myurl.com/go.php?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.myotherurl.com
```

You must do two things to achieve this on the url:

1. have a query string parameter. eg.
   `go.php?url=mysite.com` or
   `go.php?redirect=mysite.com` not
   just `go.php?mysite.com`.
2. you must URL ENCODE this query
   string parameter value. eg. `go.php?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.myotherurl.com`
   NOT `go.php?url=http://www.myotherurl.com`. In php you can use the `urlencode()` function or http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/ can do it for you if you have a small number of urls to convert.

On the PHP side of things you will use the following

```
<?php
     header('Location: '.urldecode($_GET['url']));
     exit();
?>
```

You can do other basic checks on the php side of things eg. check for a valid url format etc

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to use the `header` command.

So, in your case you would do this:

For a url in this syntax: go.php?url=thisurl

This would be the code

```
<?php
header('Location: ' . $_GET['url']);
?>
```

Comment: Make sure to use the exit() command after a header redirect to stop the script from executing further after setting the header. Also note that browsers don't have to obey this directive, so use with caution.